# Change image with radio buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have been looking for some time to find a way to have an image in a webpage change depending on what radio button in a form is selected, and every way that I've tried has been unsuccessful. I'm assuming that there must be a relatively easy way to do this, as it's not an incredibly complicated change to make, but I'm pretty new to javascript so I may just be doing something wrong. (This is my first time using StackOverflow, so I apologize if I'm asking a stupid question)

**Here is my Javascript function**

```
function  changeCardLogo() {
    switch(document.test.creditCard.value){
    case "Visa":
        document.getElementById("cardLogo").innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/visaLogo.svg'>";
        break;
    case "MasterCard":
        document.getElememtById("cardLogo").innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/masterCardLogo.png'>";
        break;
    case "PayPal":
        document.getElementById("cardLogo").innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/paypalLogo.jpg'>";
        break;
    }
}
```

**My radio buttons**

```
        <p><b>Payment Method</b><br>
    <input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="Visa" checked onClick="changeCardLogo()"> Visa <br>
    <input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="MasterCard" onClick="changeCardLogo()"> MasterCard <br>
    <input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="PayPal" onClick="changeCardLogo()"> PayPal <br></p>
```

*Note: the radio buttons are within a form named "form1", but for some reason the code didn't display properly when I included the tags

And my images are changed within **this div**

```
<div id="cardLogo" height=75></div>
```

any help that anyone can provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: For starters, you have a bug (if this was copied and pasted) for "MasterCard": 'document.getElememtById'.  Secondly, it may be simpler to overwrite the card logo's image tag directly by updating the src attribute.  What's the value present in document.text.creditCard.value?

Comment: The default value of creditCard is visa, and thanks for pointing out the typo. I had previously tried changing the src attribute directly but found that it still did not work, despite checking for syntax errors and typos for several hours.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors. First , to get form data value, you  need use:

```
document.forms["form1"].creditCard.value
```

instead of ( Why call "test" propertie when that your form name is form1 ? )

```
document.test.creditCard.value
```

Secondly, to get node by ID, correct function name is getElementById ( look your MasterCard case ).

Answer (score 2):

Le's say you have this `form` and you set some `data-*` attributes to your radio buttons representing the image name:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <p><b>Payment Method</b><br>
    <input data-img="visaLogo.svg" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="Visa" checked> Visa <br>
    <input data-img="masterCardLogo.png" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="MasterCard"> MasterCard <br>
    <input data-img="paypalLogo.jpg" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="PayPal"> PayPal <br></p>
  <div id="cardLogo" height=75></div>
</form>
```

than you might use something like: http://jsfiddle.net/axnrtosa/2/

```
var cards = document.myForm.creditCard;
var logo  = document.getElementById("cardLogo");
var event = new Event('change');

for(var i=0; i<cards.length; i++)
    cards[i].addEventListener('change', changeCardLogo, false);

cards[0].dispatchEvent(event); // Trigger change

function changeCardLogo() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src= "Graphics/"+ this.dataset.img;
  logo.innerHTML = "";        // Remove old image
  logo.appendChild( img );    // Append new image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get what you want, another one is:

```
<html>
<script>
function changeImg(value){
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    switch(value){
        case "mastercard": img.src="MasterCard.jpg";break;
        case "visa": img.src="Visa.jpg";break;
        case "paypal": img.src="PayPal.jpg";break;
        default: return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <img src="MasterCard.jpg" id="img"/>
    MasterCard: <input type="radio" name="card" value="mastercard" checked onclick="changeImg(this.value)"/>
    visa: <input type="radio" name="card" value="visa" onclick="changeImg(this.value)"/>
    paypal: <input type="radio" name="card" value="paypal" onclick="changeImg(this.value)" onclick="changeImg(this.value)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element (and its value) "document.test.creditCard.value" can't be found.

You have to access it by the way [Thibault Bach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4128485/thibault-bach) wrote, or you can pass the value of the radio button as a parameter in the function call, like this:

```
<p><b>Payment Method</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="Visa" checked onClick="changeCardLogo(this.value)"> Visa <br>
<input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="MasterCard" onClick="changeCardLogo(this.value)"> MasterCard <br>
<input type="radio" name="creditCard" value="PayPal" onClick="changeCardLogo(this.value)"> PayPal <br></p>
<div id="cardLogo" height="75"></div>
<script>
    function  changeCardLogo(v) {

        var target = document.getElementById("cardLogo");

        switch(v){
            case "Visa":
                target.innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/visaLogo.svg'>";
                break;
            case "MasterCard":
                target.innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/mastercardLogo.png'>";
                break;
            case "PayPal":
                target.innerHTML= "<img height=75 src='Graphics/paypalLogo.jpg'>";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```